# Adding and retrieving custom properties to MQ

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I am bit new to the whole MQ world so I am not sure about the specific technicalities.
I am struggling to send a message on a Websphere Mq with additional data; the additional data will then be used by another system for processing.

I am using the following code to do add additional properties to the mq; is this the correct way to do it?
Code in C#

```
IMessage sendMsg;

IMessageProducer producer;

// Create a message ---someMessage will be a xml file
sendMsg = new IMessage(someMessage);

int fileSize= size("document.pdf"); 


//add addtional message properties
sendMsg.SetStringProperty("MessageSize",fileSize);


// Send the message
producer.Send(sendMsg);
```

Also, how do i query the mq so that I get all these properties along with the actual message?

Can anyone please help; this has got me going round in circles....

Answer (score 1):

Yes using SetStringProperty,SetBooleanProperty, etc,you should be able to set the properties. For getting back the property values you should use msg.GetStringProperty,msg.GetBooleanProperty etc after the message is received.In your case it has to be something like msg.GetStringProperty(MessageSize).

Comment: I can see the value on mq.. is there a way i can pull this value as part of MQGET return value...
I.e.
`****Message properties****
MessageSize: '500‘
**** Message ****
length - 72 bytes
00000000: 5246 4820 0200

Answer (score 1):

FYI.  The MQ Knowledge Center is full of information.

Here is the page on [Message](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q111220_.htm).  Scroll down to the 'Property methods' sections.  It has all the methods to retrieve properties from a message.